# "Lost" customers in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a question, the management wants to see the "lost" customers. The lost customers are customers who haven't ordered for the last *4 months*.

The result should be in numbers by entity:

```
Entity | Lost Customers
  1           12
  2            3
```

There are 3 tables.

- tblOrder which contains the last orderdate.
- tblRelation which contains all relations / customers
- tblsysentity which contains the entity numbers

Each relation (customer) is connected to an entity in the relation table.

Comment: This should be relatively straight forward. Can you post up some sample data and the salient columns? Without knowing how the tables join, I could only tell you the theory, which I am happy to do if that is what you are after?

Comment: What is an entity?  What is a relation?  Your data structure doesn't make sense without sample data.

Comment: So someone whose last order was two years ago would be counted as lost, just as someone whose last order was five months ago would be counted as lost?  What about someone whose last order was 10 years ago?

Comment: @GordonLinoff an entity is a country and a relation is a customer.

Comment: @JoshGilfillan last ordered 10 years ago is also a lost customer

Answer (score 0):

I made up the join attributes since you did not provide them. I assume that there is a 1:N relationship between `tblRelation` and `tblOrder`. I ommit `tblsysentity` since it does not seems to be relevant.

```
SELECT *
FROM tblRelation 
WHERE tblRelation.cid NOT IN
(
    SELECT cid FROM tblOrder o
    WHERE orderdate > DATEADD(month, -4, GETDATE())
)
```

It is possible to use `NOT EXISTS` or `EXCEPT` as well

```
SELECT *
FROM tblRelation 

EXCEPT

SELECT c.*
FROM tblRelation c
JOIN tblOrder o ON c.cid = o.cid
WHERE orderdate > DATEADD(month, -4, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

With no sample data its difficult to provide a solution but in general terms you could try something like this:

```
with
-- first get lost customers
max_orderDates as (
select
   customerID
  ,max(orderDate) max_orderDate
from tblOrder o
group by customerID
having DATEADD(month, 4, max(orderDate)) < GETDATE()
)
-- now link customers with entity, and count number of lost customers per entity
select
   e.entityID as Entity
  ,count(1) as [Lost Customers]
from max_orderDates lost_c

-- join to relation
left join tblRelation rel
  on lost_c.customerID = rel.customerID

-- join to entity
left join tblsysentity e
  on rel.entityID = e.entityID

group by
   e.entityID
```

Comment: I tried this query, the result is ALL the lost customers from 4months and older. I just need the customers from who didn't order in the last 4 months.

Comment: Isn't that the same thing? Please give more detail.

Comment: Josh, this query is the result of all customers who didnt order for 4 months and older. But i want a result of the amount of customers who did not order in the last 4 months.

Comment: Can you give an example (with data) of where the query is giving an incorrect result? This will make it easier to help you.

Comment: The result of the query up here is:
    Entity Lost Customers
    NULL 1727
    1 1572
    2 1190
    4 83
    7 11
    8 622
    9 1693
    13 140
 
But that is way too high. Those are the customers who havent ordered from 4 months or older. I just need the ones who havent ordered the _last_ 4 monts